# How do you clear the gmaps4rails map cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

Currently I'm using an ajax call to display a google map.  It works fine on the first try but after leaving and going back to the page, the map renders two squares and the rest is gray. Also, the zoom in/out vertical bar does not show anymore.

I'm assuming something is being retained in memory.  Is there a gmaps4rails javascript command to clear the memory?

This is the javascript that's being used:

```
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
  Gmaps.map.map_options.maxZoom = 15;
  Gmaps.map.initialize();
  Gmaps.map.markers = <%= @json %>;
  Gmaps.map.create_markers();
  Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
  Gmaps.map.callback();
};

Gmaps.loadMaps();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer to my question. It was only happening locally.  Once I moved the code up to the server it ran fine!